# Scala Constructor pattern vs Extractor pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

What is the difference between constructor pattern and extractor pattern matching? 
In *Programming in Scala* the authors make the distinction as the constructor pattern is discussed in Ch 15 and the extractor pattern in Ch 26.

Example of the constructor pattern:

```
abstract class Expr
case class BinOp(operator: String, left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

expr match {
    case BinOp("+", e, Number(0)) => println("a deep match")
    case _ => 
}
```

Example of an extractor:

```
l match {
     case List(a,b,c) => a
     case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is expressed in the specification:

> An extractor pattern `x(p1, …, pn)` where `n ≥ 0` is of the same
>   syntactic form as a constructor pattern. However, instead of a case
>   class, the stable identifier `x` denotes **an object which has a member
>   method named  unapply or unapplySeq that matches the pattern**.

Simply put, a constructor pattern talks about decomposition of case classes, where the extractor pattern talks about any object with either an `unapply` or `unapplySeq`.

`List[A]` has a `unapplySeq` provided by the abstract `SeqFactory`:

```
/** This method is called in a pattern match { case Seq(...) => }.
 *
 *  @param x the selector value
 *  @return  sequence wrapped in an option, if this is a Seq, otherwise none
 */
def unapplySeq[A](x: CC[A]): Some[CC[A]] = Some(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example will use the `List.unapplySeq()` method.

[The Neophytes' Guide to Scala](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) has a useful explanation:

> In its most widely applied form, an extractor has the opposite role of
>   a constructor: While the latter creates an object from a given list of
>   parameters, an extractor extracts the parameters from which an object
>   passed to it was created.
>
> The Scala library contains some predefined extractors, and we will
>   have a look at one of them shortly. Case classes are special because
>   Scala automatically creates a companion object for them: a singleton
>   object that contains not only an apply method for creating new
>   instances of the case class, but also an unapply method – the method
>   that needs to be implemented by an object in order for it to be an
>   extractor.

Comment: The Neophytes guide doesn't talk about the difference between the patterns. It only conveys that extractors exist and that case classes get them automagically. Also, it doesn't  talk about extractors in the sense the specification does as to distinguish between arbitrary objects with `unapply` and case classes.